# What does 'it should be proved" mean in the following context? Could you rephrase the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's about building earthquake-resistant houses built of earth in rural areas of earthquake-prone zones. The sentence is : "Using locally available building materials as well as the skills of local craftsmen should be considered for the design of seismic-resistant (earthquake-proof) houses and **it should be proved** that the solutions are accepted by the users." Many thanks for your help.

Comment: The sentence is saying that two things should be done: 1. consideration of the use of local resources.  2.  the gathering of proof that the solutions are acceptable.

Comment: The users are perhaps the household or maybe even the workers, and the special building project that is to be undertaken is expected to satisfy them.(proved to be reliable?)

Comment: I don't see anything here that can't be addressed using any dictionary.

Comment: FumbleFingers, I perfectly know that and you should know that a dictionary isn't always the solution. Your comment is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase in context means that convincing proof should be provided to 'users' that new methods and materials are worthy of adoption. The term 'users' is a way of defining all the people who depend on the structure for commerce, shelter, or value as property. The fundamental point of the sentence is that the people who use the buildings adopt the buildings for use *and* learn the new method of construction "using local materials".  The "proof" in this context is that which convinces all users that the safety measures expressed in the design and implemented in the construction make the buildings more survivable than buildings built out of local materials up to this time.

There is no restriction in the text on type of material used, but you have stated that the material to be used in buildings is "earth" The most common method for turning earth into a construction material is to make bricks. This requires time and energy, which implies additional organization on the part of the local society.

In the context of your question and the sentence given, this is a direction for a project to convince local indigenous people to improve the traditional method of construction in order to increase the chances of their structures surviving an earthquake. The phrase in question is written using the passive voice, leaving the particular requirements completely undefined. In other words it is an attempt on the part of the writer to avoid the responsibility of describing what has to be done. So, I would rewrite the sentence "and it should be proved that the solutions are accepted by the users." with the following;

**". Introducing new tools and methods required to build earthquake resistant housing require training and cultural acceptance. The first step is to design structures that are consistent with local culture, then modify the design to improve structural integrity. The next step is training local builders to adopt the new design and building methods. The success of this plan depends on both builders and residents accepting the new design and adopting the new construction methods. The introduction of materials from outside sources must be limited to sources that are consistently available and within 48 to 96 hours travel time."**